# CSS selected using double nested class not selecting the right element

Tags: css

I'm trying to select the div that has "Trying to access this element"

```
<div id="main" class="wrapper clearfix 3-column">
   <div id="col1" class="floatleft">
      <div><img src="img/main.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="col1-grid2">
         Trying to access this element
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Doing .col1-grid2 or #main .col1-grid2 works as expected. However, why would doing .3-column .col1-grid2 not target the element?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Could you post the actual CSS?

Comment: Hi @Jay, it is .3-column .col1-grid2 {
  background-color:#e6e3db;
 }

Comment: this seems to work well here???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the selector, it's the name of the class. `3-column` is not a valid class name. It must start with a `-`, `_` or a letter (a-z or A-Z). *EDIT: updated to say not just lower case letters*